# GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP") without tilde (~)

Tags: c#, .net, environment-variables

I want to get the path of the temp folder (`C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp`).

`GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP")` works fine, but I get the path with tilde:

```
C:\Users\STANHE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\
```

.. and I need the path without the tilde:

```
C:\Users\StanHerrmann\AppData\Local\Temp\
```

Comment: Why do you feel you need the long version? The short form is perfectly valid.

Comment: I'm using a library which needs the long version. It doesn't work very well with the short version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Path.GetFullPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx) to expand it:

> If you pass in a short file name, it is expanded to a long file name.

**But...** it would be better to just use [`Path.GetTempPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath.aspx) for this, so you don't have to rely on environment variables to be correct.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will use your suggestion. :)

Comment: The two suggestions are right, even if Path.GetTempPath itself relies in the end on environment variables, it's safer to use it rather than a single call to get TEMP environment variable.

Comment: @Richard you're right. `Path.GetTempPath` calls the WinAPI function [`GetTempPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364992.aspx), which ends up reading the environment (`TMP` then `TEMP` then `USERPROFILE` then the windows directory - that last one actually bothers me now I'm aware of this behavior).